# Bayes' theorem and conditional probability?

Tags: soft-question, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

This is a bit of a soft-question, which I just happened to overhear, so please, bear with me.

"How can one derive Bayes’ theorem from the definition of conditional probability?"

After hearing said question, it got me thinking, and I tried to puzzle it out, but couldn't.

Could anyone kindly explain to me how this works?

I can't seem to wrap my head around it, so I would really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me as if I was about 10 years old mentally (which I'm starting to think I just might be).

Comment: This question doesn't really belong here. It could belong to stats site, Cross Validated. It is also common practice for users to show that they have attempted some solution to their problem, especially for such introductory material.

Comment: I think this question belongs here because it's asking how to prove a basic theorem in probability, which is one of the main subjects in math.

Comment: The trick is to understand conditional probability in terms of a Venn Diagram (it's a ratio of areas or probabilities).  If you can convince yourself of its validity in those visual terms, then it's a short step to get to Bayes' Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

When faced with this sort of question, first let us ask ourselves **what you would like to derive**. 
In this case, consider Baye's theorem: $$ P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(B\mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)}  $$

Next, consider what we know,or **from where you want to get there.** In our case, we would like to start with the conditional probability states that $ P( A \cap B)=P(A \mid B) \cdot P(B)$.

Now we can start doing what Mario Carneiro  called "algebraic manipulations". We will start with the statement of conditional probability and end up with Baye's theorem.

$$ P( A \cap B)=P(A \mid B) \cdot P(B) \Leftrightarrow P(A \mid B)=\frac{P( A \cap B)}{P(B)}  $$

Here, all we did was to divide both sides of the equation by $P(B)$. We notice that our equation now has the same form as the Baye's theorem: $P(A \mid B)= \frac {something}{P(B)} $.

With a little insight, we notice that the top term of the Baye's theorem, that is $P(B \mid A)P(A)$, is equal to $P(B \cap A)$.

This is where the commutativity the Graham evoked comes into play. It means that $P(A \cap B)=P(B \cap A)$.
Therefor, we can replace the top term in our work in progress and we obtain: $P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(B)}$. 
We then expand the new top term and we end up with our (well, Baye's) theorem: since $P(B \cap A)=P(B\mid A) \cdot P(A)$, we replace $P(B\mid A)$ and we get...
$$P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(B \mid A) \cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Baye's Theorem is: $P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(B\mid A)\times P(A)}{P(B)}$

Conditional Probability is: $P(A \cap B) = P(A \mid B)\times P(B)$

---

**Hint:** begin with: $P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap A) \quad \because\text{ commutativity of }\cap$

Comment: Though this will probably cement me as a moron, I'm going to beg for a little more help than that. Could you perhaps explain the steps to me? Yes, I really am this bad.

Comment: @ViXXaTion $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap A)=P(B|A)P(A)$. Are you familiar with algebraic manipulations?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Only to the extent that I know what they are. I know that the Distributive Law and the Associative Law exist, but I have little idea of how to use them. And definitively less idea how to apply algebraic manipulation in this case...